# clear dynamic collapsible list, empty() html(" ") is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

```html
<div data-role="page" id="leavebal_page" class="home_page_style" style="position:fixed; overflow:hidden;">
            <div data-role="content" id="leavebal_page_content"style="overflow:hidden;margin: 0;
                padding: 0;" >
                <div id="leavebal_header" style="width: 100%; margin: -2%; height:12.5%;">
                    <h4 style="text-align: center; color: white;line-height: 3;">AppName</h4>
                    <a href="#menupanel" class="ui-btn ui-btn-left ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-bars ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-nodisc-icon" style="background: transparent;">Menu</a>
                    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-arrow-l ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-nodisc-icon" style="background: transparent;" onclick="changePageForHome();">Back</a>
                </div>
                <hr style="width:100%; margin-top:-9%;">
                <div id="leave_query" class="open_tab_bckgrnd" style="margin-top: -6%;">
                     <h6 style="background-color:#D3D3D3;text-align:center;height:6%;color: #C32036;text-shadow: none;font-size: 18px;font-weight: normal;position: relative;top: 2%;">Leave Balance</h6>
                    <div data-role="collapsible-set" id="leavebalstatus">
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
```

I want to clear previous data every time I left my page. I used .empty() & html('') for this but it is not working. Please help me.

Here is my code -

```
$("#leavebalstatus").html(" ");
$("#leavebalstatus").empty();

      var leaveBallist= '';
for( i=0; i<getLeaveBal.length;i++){
              leavebalgrp_name =  getLeaveBal[i].find('Leave_Group_Name').text();
              leavebal_code = getLeaveBal[i].find('Leave_Type_Code').text();
              leavebal_name =   getLeaveBal[i].find('Leave_Name').text();

              leaveBallist += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-iconpos="right" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" style="background:white;" id="leaveBalMainData"><h3 style="margin-bottom:2%;"><div style="width:100%;" id="leaveBal_contaner"><p style="display:inline-block;width:35%;background: red;text-align:center; color:white;">'+leavebal_name+'</p><p style="display:inline-block;width:60%; margin-left:5%;">'+leavebalgrp_name+'</p></div></h3>';

              for(k=0; k<collapseArray.length;k++){
             if (i == k){

            leaveBallist += '<p style="width:100%;margin-left:5%;"><span style="width:33%; dispaly:inlne-block;float:left;">Entitled</span><span style="width:33%; dispaly:inlne-block;float:left;">Availed</span><span style="width:33%; dispaly:inlne-block;float:left;">Balance</span></p><p style="width:100%;margin-left:5%;"><span style="width:33%; dispaly:inlne-block; float:left;">'+collapseArray[i].find('LeaveEntitled').text()+'</span><span style="width:33%; dispaly:inlne-block; float:left;">'+collapseArray[i].find('LeaveAvailed').text()+'</span><span style="width:33%; dispaly:inlne-block; float:left;">'+collapseArray[i].find('LeaveBal').text()+'</span></p>';
             }

           }
              leaveBallist += '<p style="width:100%;"><hr style="width:100%;"></p><p style="width:100%;"><span style="color:red; width:100%;font-size:16px;margin-left:42%" onclick="applyLeaveForBal('+i+');">APPLY</span></p></div>';
          }

                  $('#leavebalstatus').html(leaveBallist);
    //   $('#leavebalstatus').collapsible();
       $('#leavebalstatus').collapsibleset( "refresh" );
       $('#leavebalstatus').trigger("create");
```

for clearing data from page I tried calling

```
$(document).on("pagehide", "#leavebal_page", function(event, ui){
                           alert(event.target);
                           $('#leavebalstatus').empty();
                           $('#leavebalstatus').html('');
                                           });
```

but both is not working.Thanks for help

Comment: You only need one of `.empty()` and `.html("")`; just about the first thing that `.html()` does is call `.empty()` anyway.

Comment: Yes you are right, but in my case both are not working. that's by I put it like this, but still no luck.

Comment: Can you put the snippet here and we can understand how it is working?

Comment: So, was the alert displayed?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bv7vuu3v/ `$("#leavebalstatus .ui-collapsible-content").empty();`

Comment: I tried this before ..not working...@Omar

Comment: list item entries every time append with existing list..this is the code only @trungk18

Comment: @Apurva: any error when you call                      $('#leavebalstatus').empty(); $('#leavebalstatus').html(''); ?

Comment: no error.. everything works fine..only data is overloaded again n again..@trungk18

Comment: yes alert is displayed... @AlenaKastsiukavets

Comment: What do you mean by 'data overloaded'? Do you see the same content? Was content added twice? What is the behavior right now?

Comment: Same content added every time when I visited the page.  @AlenaKastsiukavets

Comment: Can you check alert($('#leavebalstatus').length) inside pagehide?

Comment: yes just now i checked this alert and every time getting length 1 only. @AlenaKastsiukavets

Comment: Could you provide the html which was generated?

Comment: please check I added html.@AlenaKastsiukavets

Comment: I am confused... You make element `collapsible()` but in html I see `data-role="collapsible-set"`. I asked you about html which was generated in `for` loop, you provided smth different.... Please, be consistent

Comment: html generated in for loop is already there, please check code.

Comment: Which version of jquery mobile your using? From jquerymobile1.4.0 `pagehide` event is deprecated. If your using `> 1.4.0` use `pagecontainerhide` instead of `pagehide`. See the documentation http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagehide .

Answer (score 3):

Its because you are creating the value again even after the value is emptied by the following code in the snippet:

```
         $('#leavebalstatus').collapsibleset( "refresh" );
         $('#leavebalstatus').trigger("create");
```

the value is emptied but at the end again refreshed and created.

You should set a flag to check whether the pagehide event occurred and if not occurred execute above two else not.

Comment: pagehide is occurring every time & also you can see in my code that already have this two lines.

Comment: Seconded on this answer.  You may be clearing the element you wish to clear upon entry into the page, but several lines down you populate the same element with `$('#leavebalstatus').html(leaveBallist);`.  If this executes quickly, you'll never see #leavebalstatus in an empty state.

Comment: thanks @jhonAtNotion but my problem is leavebalstatus is getting data every time I'm calling my function.

Answer (score 1):

You could try with remove this way:

```
$("#leavebalstatus").children().remove();
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: its remove page completely. list is not creating using this  @jcarrera

Comment: yes I tried with pagehide but still no luck. using remove page content removed completely header as well, and using empty page content is removed but when I visit the page again..then page is not creating

Comment: But #leavebalstatus is a collapsibleset, right? If you remove the collapsiblesets' children, how could you also delete the header and the page content? Am I missing something? :)

Comment: Yes it is collapsibleset. I don't what happen with this. In my whole application every page like listview , collapsible listview, dropdown list , grid view.. every screen same issue occur. Is there any possibility to div created every time when I call the function? how can solve this issue. from last 4 @ jcarrera

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("#leavebalstatus").reset();
```

Comment: please, elaborate and extend your answer, give some introduction and explanation, or your answer might be deleted, because of the low quality post. Thank you for the understanding. Please read the **help section**, for more information on how to write and answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advise @Farside, I will keep this in mind!

Comment: André van Rensburg, but what I mean - you have to do it explicitly now, or your answer will be in the review queue on moderators desk one more time. Please, edit your answer according to [the best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can't be sure about what I'll say without testing it but maybe it can help. Last week I was working with Bootstrap and I had troubles with a modal when I tried to clean it in certain cases.

The thing was that in some situations Bootstrap was creating the modal again as a direct child of the body. So when I called the empty function it was pointing somewhere else.

My suggestion is to evaluate the `alert($('#leavebalstatus').length)` as @AlenaKastsiukavets says in the comments but changing the leavebalstatus id into a class, so that way jQuery doesn't have problems selecting more than one object.

Finally I solved it by putting the modal as a direct child of the body but obviously it's probable that the solution you need may change a bit.